# Why do I not get the Old Hat when I've been a member for over 2 years?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2013

I have been a member of Stack Overflow for **2 years and 1 month**. Why didn't I earn the **Old Hat**, then. And if I am not an old member, than what is the criteria of **old member** here?

Comment: Old hat is rare for Stack Overflow.

Comment: That edit was not inappropriate; there was no reason to roll it back.

Comment: But you can earn in on another site and wear it on stackoverflow.

Comment: The flip side is that if you joined Stack Overflow during the private beta and have remained active on the network you'll have earned the fool thing all over the place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the description of the 'Old Hat' hat:

> have a user account created in the first month of the site's existence

If you created your account 2 years and 1 month ago, then it is not in the first month of the existence of StackOverflow, so you can't get that hat.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have signed up for a site *in the first **month** of the site's existence*. See the [Old Hat description](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/old-hat):

> have a user account created in the first month of the site's existence

Stack Overflow has been around for over 5 years now, you signed up *years* after the site was created. You'd have to have been part of the [site beta in August 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/) for you to earn the Old Hat there.

Answer (score 4):

The requirement is to

> have a user account created in the first month of the site's existence

StackOverflow is much older than 2 years and 1 month.

Answer (score 3):

You will have needed to have joined Stack Overflow prior to August 13th, 2008 to earn "Old Hat" there.

If your user number is 1247 or lower and you do not have this hat on Stack Overflow, then there may be a problem with the hat awarding algorithm.